# Passing USB Port argument to included launch file

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Folks,

I have 2 launch files that i will start with executing one launch file.

In the one launch file i integrated the launch-files with  :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>

<include file="$(find curio_base)/launch/arduino_controller.launch port:=/dev/ttyUSB0" >
</include>

<include file="$(find curio_base)/launch/base_controller.launch" >
</include>

</launch>
```

I get the error:

```
RLException: while processing /home/masterkey/curio_ws/src/curio/curio_base/launch/arduino_controller.launch 
port:=/dev/ttyUSB0:
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
u'/home/masterkey/curio_ws/src/curio/curio_base/launch/arduino_controller.launch port:=/dev/ttyUSB0'
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

If I enter in the termianl:

```
roslaunch curio_base arduino_controller.launch port:=/dev/ttyUSB0
```

it works.

How do I specify the port:=/dev/ttyUSB0 expression correctly in the launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381733/passing-usb-port-argument-to-included-launch-file/) by [masterkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/71961/masterkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're trying to pass an argument to an `include`d `.launch` file.

You don't do that by including the argument in the `file` attribute of the `include` element, but by adding an `arg` child element to the `include`:

```
<include file="$(find curio_base)/launch/arduino_controller.launch">
  <arg name="port" value="/dev/ttyUSB0" />
</include>
```

Refer to [wiki/roslaunch/XML/arg](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0